# Excel formula to assign multiple tags to titles

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a list 2000 titles like below in A-Col

**A1: Titles**
A2: 10 Facebook Marketing Ideas for Small Business
A3: 10 Fun Facts About Social Media
A4: 10 Fitness Tips for Health Life

And I have about 20 popular (singular) words from the above titles in B-Col B2:B21 that I want to assign as tags for each title in C-Col

**B1: Tags**
B2: Business
B3: Social
B4: Health
B5: Fitness
B6: Marketing
B7: Facebook

So for example in C2 I want to return multiple values, so title in A2 will be labeled as  **Marketing, Business, Facebook** in C2 these are the 3 tags assigned to the title in A2.

Answer (score 0):

Labelling with multiple labels can be done in different ways. The simplest way is to create a column for each label, and enter one or zero.

Another way is working with a so-called bitmap, like following example:
"Business" tag value : 1 (binary 1)
"Social" tag value   : 2 (binary 10)
"Health" tag value   : 4 (binary 100)
...
"Facebook" tag value : 32 (binary 100000)

Labels can be combined, simply by adding them.

As a result:
"Business+Social" corresponds with value 3 (binary 0000011).
Value 37 (binary 100101) corresponds with "Business+"Health"+Facebook".

The main question for you: do you want it to be easily readable (multiple columns) or do you prefer short communication (bitmap)?

Comment: I don't want it in multiple columns, I want it in a single column. Can this be done in MS excel?

Comment: @FaizSheikh: the bitmap solution I proposed is a single-column solution. You might need to write a User-Defined Function (UDF) for this, for which you might need VBA, but it's definitively feasible.